# upload several files at once

Tags: c#, jquery, html, upload

i'm building a website with very simple cms.
I built a form already with an input type="file" already to upload pictures, but the client wants to upload several files at once. So i've looking for and I found the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com), but also found some bugs and i want to try something else.
Any help??

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that with your C# reference also comes ASP.NET? -- If so, the [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Default.aspx) has a [multi-file upload](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).

This is a plugin that uses many different technologies to upload multiple files to server like HTML5, GEARS, FLASH, HTML4, SILVERLIGHT and select the one that best fits in the user browser.

It also feature a jquery UI plugin for your upload queue.

Answer (score 0):

If they can only use a browser that supports HTML5, I would suggest using the new [multiple upload feature](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-input-multiple).  I would also implement drag-and-drop uploads like gmail has.

Answer (score 0):

one possible way is to upload a zip file via input type="file" and unzip it in the script after the upload

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/i-e-b/jQueryFileUpload.Net